# WPF grid removes shadow if itemscontrol in scrollviewer is heigher as maxheight

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a little overlay over my application. This overlay should be splittet up into 3 columns and 2 rows.

```
<ColumnDefinition width="auto"/>
<ColumnDefinition width="*"/>
<ColumnDefinition width="auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
<RowDefinition Height="400px" MaxHeight="400px"/>
```

Now I want to add 2 grid. The first on `Grid.Column=0 & Grid.Row=1` and the second on `Grid.Column=2 and Grid.Row=1`. Around both grids should be a shadow.

At the end it should look like this:

[image]

The real result looks like this:

[image]

I build it up like this:

```html
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MaxWidth="400px" MinWidth="400px" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MaxWidth="400px" MinWidth="400px" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="400px" MaxHeight="400px" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid Name="gJobs" Background="#FFF" MaxHeight="400px" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding JobMng}">
    <Grid.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="2.5" Direction="270" Color="#AA000000" Opacity=".42" RenderingBias="Performance" />
    </Grid.Effect>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}" Grid.Row="0">
      <TextBlock Foreground="#FFF" FontSize="16px" Padding="10px">Aufgaben</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PerformingJobs}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="20px">
              <!-- ... -->
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>

  <Grid Name="gNotifications" Background="#FFF" MaxHeight="400px" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding NotificationMng}">
    <!--Left Side-->
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

If I add some data to the `JobMng` or `NotificationMng` it looks like this:

[image]

**There is no shadow. In addition to this, the scrollbar got some problems. 
Does anyone of you know where my mistake it?**

Comment: You have only applied one DropShadowEffect. What is your exact issue here? Please read this and edit your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8 I can't cut more code out of it. The left side is exactly the same as the right side, that's why I removed the code of the left side. And I think the structure how I build the overlay up is important.